# How do conditionally check if a file exists in Sphinx autoclass template?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx

I am attempting to conditionally include a graphviz file into my autoclass template. Only some of my objects have these files, which is why I want to see whether the file exists before attempting to include it.

```
   {% if hasdoc('./../lib/program_data.{{ objname }}.dot') %}
   .. graphviz:: ../../lib/program_data.{{ objname }}.dot
   {% endif %}
```

I'm getting this error message:

```
Extension error (sphinx.ext.autosummary):
Handler <function process_generate_options at 0x7f8eb92a3880> for event 'builder-inited' threw an exception (exception: 'hasdoc' is undefined)
```

[hasdoc](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html#hasdoc) is a helper function listed in the [Sphinx template documentation](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/templating.html), but it doesn't seem to be available. Maybe because this is an autoclass template? I also tried os.path.exists(), but got an error saying that os was not defined.

How do I make this work?

Comment: I can't explain the error message, but I think `hasdoc` is for RST documents only.

Comment: Where did you try `os.path.exists()`? If you want to use that, `import os` is required.

Comment: Not sure where I would "import os". My conf.py file already has it.

Comment: You mention two errors, but you have not shown us how to reproduce them. But that probably does not matter anyway. You will have to rethink this. `hasdoc` cannot be used to check for the existence of arbitrary files.